# Clean dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'Fruit ': ['', 'valueone'], 'Vegetables': ['', 'value2'], 'Locations': ['', 'value3'], 'City': [], 'Assess': ['', 'value5'], 'Country': ['', 'value6'], 'Private': ['', 'value7'], 'Year': ['value8'], 'In': ['', 'value9'], 'Two': ['Clear', 'samevalue\n Remove samevalue', 'samevalue', 'Remove samevalue', 'newvalues'], 'Five': ['', 'yes']}
```

Dictionary values are in a list and have the following attributes that require cleaning:

1. empty ('') elements should be deleted
2. Duplicate (e.g. 'samevalue', 'remove samevalue' should be just 'samevalue' in a list)

Is there any direct way of accessing and modifying dictionaries values rather than nested list and ignoring or removing/deleting elements by index or by matches?

something different than this example:

```
clean = {'Fruit ': ['', 'valueone'], 'Vegetables': ['', 'value2'], 'Locations': ['', 'value3'], 'City': [], 'Assess': ['', 'value5'], 'Country': ['', 'value6'], 'Private': ['', 'value7'], 'Year': ['value8'], 'In': ['', 'value9'], 'Two': ['Clear', 'samevalue\n Remove samevalue', 'samevalue', 'Remove samevalue', 'newvalues'], 'Five': ['', 'yes']}
for i in clean.values():
    for nested in i:
        if 'Clear' not in nested:
            print(nested)
```

output:

```
valueone
value2
value3
value5
value6
value7
value8
value9
samevalue
 Remove samevalue
samevalue
Remove samevalue
newvalues
yes
```

This way I loose pairs of keys and values, I can't control and seems to be more complicated than it actually is

Desired output:

```
{'Fruit ': ['valueone'], 'Vegetables': ['value2'], 'Locations': ['value3'], 'City': ['None'], 'Assess': ['value5'], 'Country': ['value6'], 'Private': ['value7'], 'Year': ['value8'], 'In': ['value9'], 'Two': ['samevalue', 'newvalues'], 'Five': ['yes']}
```

Comment: What is the logic that will merge  'samevalue', 'remove samevalue'  to one string?

Comment: @balderman the logic is that it checks if the same string words appear in that case only unique are left

Answer (score 1):

Following is the answer to part 1. of your question.

```
clean = {'Fruit ': ['', 'valueone'], 'Vegetables': ['', 'value2'], 'Locations': ['', 'value3'], 'City': [], 'Assess': ['', 'value5'], 'Country': ['', 'value6'], 'Private': ['', 'value7'], 'Year': ['value8'], 'In': ['', 'value9'], 'Two': ['Clear', 'samevalue\n Remove samevalue', 'samevalue', 'Remove samevalue', 'newvalues'], 'Five': ['', 'yes']}
for key, value in clean.items():
    if '' in value:
        value.remove('')
print(clean)
```

Output

```
{'Fruit ': ['valueone'], 'Vegetables': ['value2'], 'Locations': ['value3'], 'City': [], 'Assess': ['value5'], 'Country': ['value6'], 'Private': ['value7'], 'Year': ['value8'], 'In': ['value9'], 'Two': ['Clear', 'samevalue\n Remove samevalue', 'samevalue', 'Remove samevalue', 'newvalues'], 'Five': ['yes']}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean for part 2. and should 'Clear' be deleted as well?

Comment: if 'Clear' in value:
    value.remove('Clear')

but is there any better solution than that? Also, would like to get rid of duplicates as well

Comment: Did my answer work for you so far? What do you mean, is there a better solution? And what do you mean by duplicates? Why is 'remove samevalue' duplicate with 'samevalue'? Is 'pineapple' duplicate with 'apple'?